# Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jestjs, react-testing-library

I added react router for basic navigation and works fine, but when I run a test it returns an error.

```
Error: Uncaught [Error: Invariant failed: You should not use Switch outside a Router]
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Normalize } from "styled-normalize";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import FooterBarNavigator from "./navigators/FooterBarNavigator";
import Favorites from "./pages/Favorites";
import Finder from "./pages/Finder";
import Notifications from "./pages/Notifications";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Normalize />
      <FooterBarNavigator />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/favorites" component={Favorites} />
        <Route exact path="/finder" component={Finder} />
        <Route exact path="/notifications" component={Notifications} />
        <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

FooterBarNavigator.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import homeIcon from "../../assets/icons/home.svg";
import favoritesIcon from "../../assets/icons/favorite.svg";
import serachIcon from "../../assets/icons/search.svg";
import notificationsIcon from "../../assets/icons/notifications.svg";
import profileIcon from "../../assets/icons/profile.svg";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const FooterBarNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <StyledFooterBarNavigator>
      <Link to="/">
        <StyledSectionIcon src={homeIcon} alt="" />
      </Link>
      <Link to="/favorites">
        <StyledSectionIcon src={favoritesIcon} alt="" />
      </Link>
      <Link to="/finder">
        <StyledSectionIcon src={serachIcon} alt="" />
      </Link>
      <Link to="/notifications">
        <StyledSectionIcon src={notificationsIcon} alt="" />
      </Link>
      <Link to="/profile">
        <StyledSectionIcon src={profileIcon} alt="" />
      </Link>
    </StyledFooterBarNavigator>
  );
};

const StyledFooterBarNavigator = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  align-items: center;
`;

const StyledSectionIcon = styled.img`
  height: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto auto 5px auto;
  display: block;
`;

export default FooterBarNavigator;
```

app.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from '../../components/App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const linkElement = getByText(/home/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-lazyload": "^2.6.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "styled-normalize": "^8.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: In your test you don't render App inside any router context, unlike when you actually run the app and render it inside the BrowserRouter. See https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your index.js you correctly wrap your routes by containing the `<App />` component with the `<BrowserRouter />`, but you haven't done this in the test, so just change:

```
const { getByText } = render(<App />);
```

to:

```
const { getByText } = render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

The full new test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from '../../components/App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
  const linkElement = getByText(/home/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing answer!